# rails + angularjs loading values into textfields on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When using AngularJS with a rails application I've hit a problem when editing records the value of the text fields is set to blank. Is there a way to tell AngularJS to use the values rails gives the form elements as the initial value?

I've put together a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

http://jsfiddle.net/YUza7/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already stated in your answer, you can use ng-init.

A more "Angular way" of doing it would be to modify your $scope/data model and not use the value parameter on your form elements.

See also [AngularJS - Value attribute on an input text box is ignored when there is a ng-model used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m)

Comment: Are you saying my rails controller should return 'json' instead of rendering the html template?

Comment: If your rails controller is only rendering the HTML template (and not the AngularJS controller code too, which is where I was hoping you could initialize your $scope properties), then ng-init is the only approach.

Answer (score 5):

Used ng-init directive as it loads initial values before running any of your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/YUza7/17/