# AngularJS controller and methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner in angularjs with a few questions about controllers.
Here's my example controller:

```
function exampleController($scope)
{
   $scope.sampleArray = new Array();

   $scope.firstMethod = function()
   {
      //initialize the sampleArray
   };

   $scope.secondMethod = function()
   {
      this.firstMethod();
   };
};
```

Here are my questions:

- How I can call `firstMethod` from `secondMethod`? Is the way I did it correct, or is better way?
- How I can create a constructor for the controller? I need to call the secondMethod that call the firstMethod that initialize the sampleArray?
- How I can call a specific method from html code? I found ng-initialize but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You call a method the same way you declared it:

```js
$scope.secondMethod = function() {
  $scope.firstMethod();
};
```

Which you can also call from HTML like so:

```html
<span>{{secondMethod()}}</span>
```

But controllers don't really have "constructors" - they're typically used just like functions. But you can place initialization in your controller function and it will be executed initially, like a constructor:

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.firstMethod = function() {
    //initialize the sampleArray
  };

  $scope.secondMethod = function() {
    $scope.firstMethod();
  };

  $scope.firstMethod();
}
```

Comment: Isn't $scope deprecated in neweer versions of AngularJS?

Comment: @RaulLuna Yes, but the answer is 4.5 years old. :-)

Comment: Er... well, but looking in google appears this answer. I thought it worth mention it.

Answer (score 7):

you call the first method by using $scope.

So

```
   $scope.secondMethod = function()
   {
      $scope.firstMethod();
   };
```

Not really sure what you mean in your second question.

For your third quesiton, you can either have the method run automatically "onload" on controller, OR run it via an front-end angular binding.

e.g. 
**Run Automatically**

```
function exampleController($scope)
{
   $scope.sampleArray = new Array();

   $scope.firstMethod = function()
   {
      //initialize the sampleArray
   };

   $scope.secondMethod = function()
   {
      $scope.firstMethod();
   };


   $scope.secondMethod(); // runs automatically.

};
```

**Run on binding**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController"> <!-- example controller set up in namespace -->

<button class="btn" ng-click="secondMethod()">Run Second Method</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

@Josh and @Christopher already covered your questions, so I won't repeat that.

> I found ng-initialize but I can't know how to use that :-(

The directive is actually [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit).  Sometimes (e.g., if you are starting to use Angular in parts of an application and you still need to dynamically generate a view/HTML page server-side), ng-init can sometimes a useful way to initialize something.  E.g.,

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
   <form name="myForm">
     <input type="text" ng-model="folder" ng-init="folder='Bob'">
```

Here's an example where someone needed to use ng-init: [rails + angularjs loading values into textfields on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703820/rails-angularjs-loading-values-into-textfields-on-edit)

I'd also like to mention that controllers are not singletons.  If you use ng-view, each time you go to a different route, a new controller is created.  The controller associated with the view you are leaving is destroyed, and the controller associated with the view you are going to is executed.  So that "initialization code" in a controller could get executed multiple times while an app is running.  E.g, if you visit a page, go elsewhere, then come back, the same controller function (and its "initialization code") would be executed twice.

If you want something to truly run once, put it in a service or in a [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module)'s config() or run() methods.  (Services are [singletons](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), and hence each service is instantiated only once, so initialization code in a service is only run once.)

Comment: I have one of those cases where ng-init can't be avoided. There's lots of warnings against using it ... and using it is definitely a hack that makes unit testing harder. But sometimes ya gotta do what ya gotta do...