# how we can define a function in controller with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

how we can define a function in angular JS i was trying a function , but when i load my page it says in console `SimpleController()` is not a function. may b i'm doing some syntax mistake

HTML

```
<div ng-app>

 name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">

 <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="custName in customers | filter: name | orderBy:name">{{ custName.name }} - {{ custName.city | uppercase}} - {{ custName.address }}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

My Contorller

```
function SimpleController($scope){

        $scope.customers = [

            {
                name:'John Doe',
                city:'Aurora',
                address:'Dickenson'
            },
            {
                name:'Daniel Pervaiz',
                city:'Denver',
                address:'Country Lane'
            },
            {
                name:'Arooj Paul',
                city:'Jesu',
                address:'Green Valley'
            }

        ];

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654059/function-inside-the-angularjs-controller

Comment: How is SimpleController connected to your app ? RTFM or start from an Ionic "Tabs" starter example : you'll get a good structure and correct syntax to refer to.

Comment: I updated my answer below with working code. I think you did not define your ng-app properly or controller. Unless you did not post all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.customers = [
            {
                name:'John Doe',
                city:'Aurora',
                address:'Dickenson'
            },
            {
                name:'Daniel Pervaiz',
                city:'Denver',
                address:'Country Lane'
            },
            {
                name:'Arooj Paul',
                city:'Jesu',
                address:'Green Valley'
            }

        ];
    
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example8-production</title>  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">

 <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="custName in customers | filter: name | orderBy:name">{{ custName.name }} - {{ custName.city | uppercase}} - {{ custName.address }}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure if your controller is defined properly.

[AngularJS controller and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407999/angularjs-controller-and-methods)

Also make sure ng-App is declared properly.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular relies on the concept of modules. Make sure your app is structured like this :

## app.js

```
angular.module('the_name_of_my_app', [
    'ionic', 
    'ngMaterial',
    'the_name_of_my_app.controllers', 
    'the_name_of_my_app.services',
    'the_name_of_my_app.directives'
]
)

.run(function( /* Inject whatever is needed */ ) {

}
.config.run(function( /* Inject any Provider, and routes definitions */ ) {

});
```

## controllers.js

```
 angular.module('the_name_of_my_app.controllers', [])  

.controller('SimpleController', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope', // another dependency injection example
    '$mdDialog', // another dependency injection example
    '$timeout',// another dependency injection example
    function
    (
    $scope,
    $rootScope, // another dependency injection example
    $mdDialog, // another dependency injection example
    $timeout // another dependency injection example
    ) 
    {
...

    }]) 

.controller('AnotherController', [  // ...
```

## index.html

You also need to reference your app in your view :

```
<div ng-app="the_name_of_my_app">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't registering your controller it'd look like this on Angular 1.4.9:

```
angular.js:12722 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined
```

And this on Angular 1.0.8:

```
angular.js:5930 Error: Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined
```

The fact that your error says `SimpleController()` shows me that the code you have in your question is probably not responsible for your error (or using a version of Angular I haven't tried - I tried to oldest and newest available on plnkr.co).

To fix this you should:

- Clear your browser cache.
- Make sure your `ng-app` (or whatever you use to bootstrap) has the correct main module specified - looks like you don't have one in your question for some reason?
- Make sure the source directory you're looking in matches the directory of the server serving the static content.
- Search for all instances of `SimpleController` in your source directory - it looks like it might be outside the context of a view using the `ng-controller` directive due to the `()` (or different version of Angular with a differently formatted message).