# how to inject spring ModelAndView object attributes in to an Angular module?

Tags: spring, angularjs, code-injection, modelandview

My application uses SpringMVC with apache velocity. Now I am going to add Angularjs controllers to the *.vm files(velocity files). I am finding a problem in accessing the objects set in the ModelAndView objects returned by the Spring controllers.

Can someone give me a simple example on how to do the same?

Example:
**Controller.java**

```
ModelAndView mav = ControllerUtil.createModelView();
String dataSource = Constant.DATA_SOURCE;
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) mav.getModel().get("httpSession");  
**mav.addObject("dataSource", dataSource);**
```

**Please give an example on how to get the 'dataSource' value inside the AngularJS module.**

Thanks in Advance,
DBKnot Team

Comment: I don't know much about SpringMVC, but is this topic relevant?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with velocity but I'm too trying to find a way to accomplish what you seem to be trying to do.

I'm currently exploring (tested it too) this approach. Use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse your object into a String. This can either be done on the controller or in the JSP through a custom tag.

Example:

```
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result =  jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle it
    }
    **mav.addObject("dataSource", result);**
```

On the HTML/JSP/Whatever have something like

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init(${dataSource})">...</div>
```

and have your controller's init method handle the rest.

**NOTE**

As always you should read the documentation, and **AngularJS recommends** that the model should be initialized through AJAX requests, not obtained from the DOM (which is what happens here).

I would love to see alternatives to this

Comment: One important thing to note, this strategy is very vulnerable. If your dataSource has quotes/double quotes in it you can run into trouble