# AngularJS: read initial value of ngModel.$viewValue from different directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to read the initial value ngModel.$viewValue from different directive.

```
# coffee script
app.directive 'directive', -> 
  return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) ->
      ........
           console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue) # does give NaN!

           ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('something'); # only after setting reading does work
           console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: this is about directive -> directive communication using the ngModelController API

Answer (score 7):

I just fixed it myself... stupid :)

```
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) ->

        scope.$watch(ngModelCtrl, ->
          console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue)
        )
```

does work! yippieh!

Answer (score 2):

No need to watch and ng-init is bad. Something like..

```
      return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                var value = getter(scope);

           }
        };
```

Here `value` will give the initial bound value in model.

Comment: Is this the best way? I'm unclear since this or the `$watch` could both work.. this seems like less overhead

Comment: @Claudiu intention here is to avoid the overhead of watch

Answer (score 1):

put your actions within a $timeout... like what you do with $apply, so your code will run after $digest finished it's process...

like this:

```
link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) { //Ctrl will bind to required ones
                //ctrl[0] -> ngModel
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.parentId = ctrl[0].$viewValue;
                    scope.startUp();
                }, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with some value from HTML inside your directive you should use ngInit. It will look like

```
<div directive ng-init="variable='value'"></div>
```

I faced the same problem, and it turned out that what I was doing was not an Angular way. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values) for more details

Comment: This is not the fix... see my post above. kind regards.