# How to access $modelValue and $viewValue from inside custom directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

While trying to access `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` from inside custom directives, I am getting `null`.

```js
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('dogInfo', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: "<div> Dog's name: {{dogname}}<br>View Name: {{viewValue}}<br>Model Value: {{modelValue}}<br> Tag name: {{tagName}}</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.viewValue = controller.$viewValue;
            scope.modelValue = controller.$modelValue;
            scope.tagName = controller.$name;
        }
    }});

function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.dogname = 'Hero';  // now    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <p ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
       <dog-info ng-model="dogname" name="Doggggyyy"/>.
    </p>
</div>
```

I am getting this output :

```
Dog's name: Hero
View Name: null
Model Value: null
Tag name: Doggggyyy
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cxdun3y8/3/

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458383/angularjs-read-initial-value-of-ngmodel-viewvalue-from-different-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
demo.directive('dogInfo', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: "<div> Dog's name: {{dogname}}<br>View Name: {{model.$viewValue}}<br>Model Value: {{modelValue}}<br> Tag name: {{tagName}}</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.model = controller;
            scope.viewValue = controller.$viewValue;
            scope.modelValue = controller.$modelValue;
            scope.tagName = controller.$name;
        }
    }});
```

Pay attention to how I pass data to the view

Comment: I don't get it.. you only created an alias for the controller and directly accessed the viewValue property in the template. Why shouldn't my approach work ?

Comment: Because ina  first case you got the link to the direct value which is empty (for now) and will change only then.
In a second case you get object, and value will be reevauated each digest. And always will be actual

Comment: ok.. Can I get the viewValue in the link function itself ? I need it to set it in scope so that I can access it in the template..

Comment: What do you mean? Just $scope.value

Comment: I want to retrieve 'Hero' (value of 'dogname') inside the link function.

Comment: I see. You can achive this with several ways. Most natural, is to always ask ngModelController. like this: 
function callTheDog() {return  ngModelCtrl.$viewValue + 'was called';    }
But also you can push yout listner to the ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners and when value will be change, you will be notifie, so you can do smth with your value.

Answer (score 0):

According to answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458383/angularjs-read-initial-value-of-ngmodel-viewvalue-from-different-directive) there are three working solutions

1) Using `$timeout` to wait until first digest end

```js
$timeout(function() {
  initialViewValue = controller.$viewValue;
}, 0)
```

2) Using `scope.watch`

```js
const off = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, () => {
  initialViewValue = controller.$viewValue;
  off();
});
```

3) Using `$parse` to get value immediately

```js
const getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
let initialViewValue = getter(scope);
```

Also viewValue available as argument inside formatter callback

```js
controller.$formatters.push(function(value) {
   viewValue = value
});
```

You'll probably want to remove callback if you only want to get initial value