# how to serialize div in angular on load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using angular js version 1.2.

Basically i am creating object in server based on screen to do this i need to pass to server

how can i convert a 'div' onload of screen to json using angularjs?

html looks likes this:

```
<div id="settingsholder"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="user.firstName" />
  <input ng-model="user.lastName" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
    <hr/>  
    {{user | json}}
</div>
```

js :

```
    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.user = { };
    }
```

jsfiddele: http://jsfiddle.net/bpbhat777/2grw1je0/

i want it to be like this
http://jsfiddle.net/bpbhat777/dbg2u5ck/

without setting firstname and lastName .It need not to be firstname and lastName , in screen ng-model may be any object

Comment: what is the use case?

Comment: in server i am creating object based on screen :)

Comment: not much of an explanation. Put more effort into questions and you will get answers that fit the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="settingsholder"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="user.firstName" ng-init="user.firstName=''" />
  <input ng-model="user.lastName" ng-init="user.lastName=''" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
    <hr/>  
    {{user | json}}
</div>
```

and remove `$scope.user = { };` from controller

WITHOUT ng-init

```
 <div id="settingsholder"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="user.firstName"  />
      <input ng-model="user.lastName"/>
      <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
        <hr/>  
        {{user | json}}
 </div>

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.user = {firstName:'',lastName:''};
 }
```

Comment: I dont want to give like this ` $scope.user = {firstName:'',lastName:''};` I will not know what will be the content ,Now i am using ng-init only :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `angular.toJson()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

There are several ways to update $scope on page load. I personally prefer to use `init()`:

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.user);
}

$scope.init();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbg2u5ck/2/

---

After reading and re-reading your question, it seems to me you want to populate the `$scope` with pre-loaded html values (an empty string in your case). This is not the way Angular works, please take the time to read this article if you want to populate `$scope` with html values: [Angular js init ng-model from default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values)

Comment: this doesn't populate the object properties

Comment: I understand now what he wants :) I updated the fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have any idea what the use of it. but if you really need that `ng-init` might be the option

```
<div id="settingsholder" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="user.firstName" ng-init="user.firstName=''" />
    <input ng-model="user.lastName" ng-init="user.lastName=''" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
    <hr/>{{user | json}}
```

check the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gayancc/2grw1je0/1/)

Comment: you can do something like this `$scope.display = angular.toJson($scope.user);` and then on the view you can just call `{{display}}` but that also you have to initialized on controller level