# why does value attribute in html doesn't work when used with ng-model in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. Trying to use it to build simple applications. I have a textbox in html with a default initial value of "Abc".

```
<input type="text" value="Abc">
```

Now, I want to fetch the value which is there in textbox. For that I am using ng-model directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="demo" value="Abc">
```

But as soon as I enter ng-model directive in input, the default value in text box disappears and it shows a blank textbox. Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to initialize your model instead of using value. check out this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the desired functionality - `Angular way`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="demo" value="Abc">

function Main($scope) {
  $scope.demo = 'Abc';
}
```

Another workaround is by using `ng-init`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="demo" ng-init="demo='Abc'" value="Abc">
```

For reference : [Input default value](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/Hn3eztNHFXw/wk3HyOl9fhcJ)