# AngularJs and ASP.NET MVC 5 - ng-model overriding textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form built using ASP.NET MVC 5 using `@Html.TextBoxFor` to populate the form with my model (e.g, after a form navigation or server side validation failure).

I have now introduced a client side address lookup using Angular which means some of the form fields are now decorated with `ng-model` to enable the Angular lookup to populate the searched address.

e.g.:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Town, new { @class="form-control", ng_model="address.town" })
```

Adding the `ng-model` now overrides the value set from the MVC model when the page is reloaded.

Viewing the source in the browser shows that the textbox value is set correctly to `Town` from the MVC model but Angular then comes along and populates it with `address.town` which is empty so the form displays no value.

How can I prevent Angular from doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to force a value from MVC

```
<input name="Town" type="text" ng-model="address.town" ng-init="address.town= @Model.Town" />

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Town, new { ng_model="address.town", ng_init="address.town= Model.Town" })
```

Alternatively, I use a directive which I found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567485/2030565

```
app.directive('input', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.ngModel) {
                val = attrs.value || element.text();
                $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, val);
            }
        }
}; });
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer than mine.  +1

Comment: You could also use `ng_value` instead of `ng_init`

Comment: The directive is awesome! tx

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable in a Javascript section at the bottom of the server template that your Angular controller assigns to the model on initialization.

```
<script>
     My.Namespace.town = @Html.Raw(Model.Town);
</script>
```