# AngularJs and ASP.NET MVC 5 - ng-model overriding SELECT selected OPTION

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Following on from my previous question here:

[AngularJs and ASP.NET MVC 5 - ng-model overriding textbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552568/angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-5-ng-model-overriding-textbox-value)

I am now having the same problem with a SELECT.

I have a form built using ASP.NET MVC 5 using `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` to populate the form with my model (e.g, after a form navigation or server side validation failure).

I have now introduced a client side function using Angular (1.4.7) which means the SELECT is now decorated with `ng-model` to enable the Angular function to use the selected value.

e.g.:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.MyEnum, 
                          new { @class="form-control", ng_model="obj.myEnum" })
```

Adding the `ng-model` now overrides the selected option set from the MVC model when the page is reloaded.

Viewing the source in the browser shows that the selected option is set correctly from the MVC model but there is an extra option which is being selected:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" 
        name="MyEnum" ng-model="obj.myEnum">
    <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

**How can I prevent this so that `Option1` stays selected?**

Using the directive from my previous question does not work as a SELECT does not have a value attribute.

The `ng_init` also does not work on a SELECT

Comment: just saw a question on this a couple days ago.  the answer was to use ng-init.  ill see if I can find the link

Comment: found the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552568/angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-5-ng-model-overriding-textbox-value

Comment: that was my question, the one I linked to in this question! :) I tried ng-init, it doesn't work on a SELECT

Comment: sorry about that.  I didn't see your link and didn't see ng-init in the code that you had shown so was hoping that would work for you :)

Comment: 1.4.7 - I've edited the question to include that

Comment: Seems `ng-init` stopped working on select in 1.4.0-beta.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a directive that should help in your case:

```
app.directive('initSelect', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var select = element[0];

      if (!select.options.length || !attrs.ngModel) return;

      var initialValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

      $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, initialValue);
    }
  }
}]);
```

It will first retrieve the value of the selected option, in your case "1". It will then use the `$parse` service to set the correct ngModel value.

After this the select should render correctly.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2VvkGfsPW94SPSVW6iUN?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! thanks I changed it slightly and named it just `'select'` so it will work on any select in my controller without having to add `init-select` to each one.

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, I should've just named it `select` too, good catch :)