# Remember selected checkboxes in modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, modal-dialog

This is scenario that I need. When i open modal box and check some checkboxes, next time when I open i want to be selected checkboxes from first time. Below is my code.

**Main Controller modal function**

```
  function openModal() {
            vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                size: 'lg',
                templateUrl: "/template.html",
                controller: 'ModalController as vm',
                resolve: {
                    refFY: function () {
                        return vm.refFY;
                    }
                }
            });

            vm.modalInstance .result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $log.info('Modal ok-ed ', selectedItem);
                vm.fySelections = selectedItem;
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        }
```

**Modal controller**

```
function ModalController($uibModalInstance, $log, refFY) {
        var fvm= this;
        fvm.refFY = refFY;
        fvm.fySelections = [];

        $log.info(fvm);

        function dismissFYSelectionModal() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }

        function confirmFYSelectionModal() {
            $log.debug(fvm.fySelections);
            $uibModalInstance.close(fvm.fySelections);
        }

        function selectAll() {
            fvm.fySelections = angular.copy(fvm.refFY);
        }

        function resetAll() {
            fvm.fySelections = [];
        }

        fiscalyearvm.dismissFYSelectionModal = dismissFYSelectionModal;
        fiscalyearvm.confirmFYSelectionModal = confirmFYSelectionModal;
        fiscalyearvm.selectAll = selectAll;
        fiscalyearvm.resetAll = resetAll;
    }
```

** modal view body**

```
    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12" data-ng-repeat="fy in fvm.refFY" data-ng-show="fvm.refFY.length > 0">
                        <div class="ckbox ckbox-primary">
                            <label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="fvm.fySelections" data-checklist-value="fy">
                            {{fy.year}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the saved setting to persist after the session ends or can it reset with the session?

Comment: No, i don't need, they can be reset

Comment: @user2687646 you have solution if i dont need after session ends?

Comment: I have a solution either way, they just look a little different. Last question: Do you need it to work in older browsers like IE 9 and such?

Comment: Oh god I just realized you're using Angular... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the checkbox's states in local storage. This module looks pretty solid: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

You'll want to configure the session storage option in that module via the `setStorageType()` as session storage is only persistent for the session whereas local storage is persistent until you clear your browsing data for that page.

Alternatively you could access the `sessionStorage()` API directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

This has a good method for pre-filling inputs with a modal that's been added to your scope in angular: [Angular js init ng-model from default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values)

Instead of using text values use Booleans to set the `ng-checked` attribute and you should be in business.

Comment if you have problems.