# Get object data with 2 dropdown menus + update Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227396/create-two-dynamic-dropdown-menus) question I need to get the selected values to my AngularJS controller.
To use the same example like in the previous question let´s say you can select your destination with two drop-downs. You first select your country then you can choose a city. If you hit that `Submit` button the whole object should get passed to the controller. The whole object is needed due to the fact that the destination-object contains several attributes like `uniqueID`, `currency` or `population` (This case is just an example, don´t worry if the attributes doesn't make sense).
So to sum up: all of the objects data just be passed to the controller not just the two which are displayed at the GUI.
In the first step I just want to print the data on the console to see if all needed data was passed.

```js
var app = angular.module('AngularApp', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.message = "Select Your Destination";
  vm.data = [
    { city: 'Berlin',         country: 'Germany',  id: 'GerBer_01',   currency: 'EURO'},
    { city: 'Hamburg',        country: 'Germany',  id: 'GerHam_02',   currency: 'EURO'},
    { city: 'Munich',         country: 'Germany',  id: 'GerMun_03',   currency: 'EURO'},
    { city: 'New York',       country: 'USA',      id: 'UsaNY_04',    currency: 'DOLLAR'},
    { city: 'Whashington DC', country: 'USA',      id: 'UsaWDC_05',   currency: 'DOLLAR'},
    { city: 'Paris',          country: 'France',   id: 'FraPar_06',   currency: 'EURO'}
  ];
  
  $scope.submit = function(){  
    
    console.log($scope.city);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="AngularApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as Main" class="container">
    <h1>{{Main.message}}</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Country</label>
        <select name="country_select" ng-model="country" class="form-control">
          <option ng-selected="$first" ng-repeat="option in Main.data | unique: 'country'" value="{{option.country}}">{{option.country}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>City</label>
        <select name="city_select" ng-model="city" class="form-control">
   <option ng-selected="$first" ng-repeat="option in Main.data | filter:{country: country}" value="{{option}}">{{option.city}}</option>
</select>
      </div>
      <br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**NOTE:**
The selection of the country and city is buggy as you can see if you press the `submit` button the value of `city` will be `undefined` at the beginning despite of the fact that it is marked as `selected` in the code. Also if you change the country but the default-city stays the `city` value won´t be updated either.

---

**EDIT**

As [@Ruhul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242846/get-object-data-with-2-dropdown-menus/39242987#39242987) suggested I changed my HTML to store the whole object in the `value`.

```
<select name="city_select" ng-model="city" class="form-control">
   <option ng-selected="$first" ng-repeat="option in Main.data | filter:{country: country}" value="{{option}}">{{option.city}}</option>
</select>
```

I also changed the `submit` method to only print the object to the console.

```
$scope.submit = function(){

  console.log($scope.city);
}
```

**BUT**
I still have problems with the initial value and the selected value. I will explain my problem a bit further:

**Initial problem:**

1. Reload the snippet
2. The drop-down shows country: Germany and city: Berlin
3. Press the `submit` button
4. **Suggestion**: the console shows the information of Berlin
5. **Actual result**: the console shows an `undefined` object

**Change Problem**

1. Click on country: USA and city: Washington
2. Click `submit` and the info of Washington is displayed in the console
3. Select **ONLY** the country France, don´t select a city. We´ll use the displayed default one: Paris
4. Click `submit` again
5. **Suggestion:** The information of Paris will be displayed due to the fact that it is selected in the lower drop-down
6. **Actual Result:** The information of Washington is displayed again: the city hasn´t been updated!

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your second select as shown below, you are missing "value"??::
Bye doing this you will have your entire object in `ng-model="city"`

```
    <select name="city_select" ng-model="city" class="form-control">
      <option ng-selected="$first" ng-repeat="option in Main.data | filter:{country: country}" value="{{option}}">{{option.city}}</option>
    </select>
```