# Context dictionary from Django template to Angular

Tags: angularjs, django, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I am building a web app and I want to know what is the best and the safest way to pass a variable from a django context dictionary to Angular.

I have access to a variable of the context dictionary from Django template. **Should I use ng-init to pass that value to an Angular variable?**

It is about a user profile page and I want the user to be able to update his Data. The Data is initialized when calling the view but when I want him to update that Data i want to post using an Angular JS variable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the data as the initial value of each form tag. [This answer has a useful "initial" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823590/5520354) to do it in a way that would allow you to use the form even without Angular.

```
<input name="profile[name]" value="Joe" ng-model="profile.name" initial>
```

With that, Angular would take the initial value fro the `value` attribute (as it should be), so that your form would have an initial value even without Angular running.