# Angular.js and HTML5 date input value -- how to get Firefox to show a readable date value in a date input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, angularjs

I have an HTML5 date input and I would like its value to be set to the value of the date property in my model by default. I'm not too fussy about formatting since Chrome seems to decide that for me anyway based on my locale, but ideally the format would be consistently `dd/MM/yyyy`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq65z/5/)**

This is how I set up my input:

```
<input type="date" 
       ng-model="date" 
       value="{{ date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" />
```

This works fine on Chrome, and I see the following by default:

[image: Chrome displaying the formatted value of the date]

*(I still don't quite understand why the value had to be given in `yyyy-MM-dd`, if Chrome still formats it based on my locale, but that's a different question.)*

My issue is with Firefox not showing the date's value in the way I've specified. I think this has to do with binding the input to the `date` model, because I can specify pretty much any string in the `value` attribute, and I will still see the long date string in the input by default:

[image: Firefox showing datestring]

If I remove `ng-model="date"` from the input tag, Firefox nicely displays any value I give it. I didn't think the model that an input was bound to actually had any effect on its default value?

I understand the date input isn't supported universally, but seeing as it's supposed to fall back on a simple text input, I don't see why its value won't simply be `2013-08-05`, as specified by angular's date filter.

**So, how do I get Firefox to accept my formatted value in the date input?**

---

**NOTE** After the edits have been done by the user, I will of course perform validation and convert each date input value into a proper `Date` object. Not sure if this is relevant to the question, but putting it out there just in case, because the input formats would obviously need to be consistent for the date conversion to work the same in all browsers. Problematic, of course, with Chrome deciding the input format for me...

Comment: Have you tried with the correct format at the initialisation (like here :http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Vq65z/7/ ) ? it could be something like : `$scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(),'MM/dd/yyyy') `

Comment: @DotDotDot This works fine because the date in that case will be a string. However, I prefer the date to be an actual javascript date object because I need to manipulate it in all kinds of ways, and it is also more semantic. But basically your suggestion is my current hack, yes. I am using a temporary string for both the model the input is bound to and its value, and converting it to a date on form submit.

Comment: I don't agree with the closure as it's on topic, describes the problem with code to reproduce it, and states what the problem is.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The problem is that [`value` is ignored when `ng-model` is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m).

Firefox, which doesn't currently support `type="date"`, will convert all the values to string. Since you (rightly) want `date` to be a real `Date` object and not a string, I think the best choice is to create another variable, for instance `dateString`, and then link the two variables:

```xml
<input type="date" ng-model="dateString" />
```

```js
function MainCtrl($scope, dateFilter) {
    $scope.date = new Date();

    $scope.$watch('date', function (date)
    {
        $scope.dateString = dateFilter(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    });

    $scope.$watch('dateString', function (dateString)
    {
        $scope.date = new Date(dateString);
    });
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Vq65z/13/)</kbd>

The actual structure is for demonstration purposes only. You'd be better off creating your own directive, especially in order to:

- allow formats other than `yyyy-MM-dd`,
- be able to use [`NgModelController#$formatters`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) and [`NgModelController#$parsers`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) rather than the artifical `dateString` variable (see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) on this subject).

Please notice that I've used `yyyy-MM-dd`, because it's a format directly supported by the JavaScript `Date` object. In case you want to use another one, you must [make the conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript) yourself.

---

**EDIT**

Here is a way to make a clean directive:

```js
myModule.directive(
    'dateInput',
    function(dateFilter) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            template: '<input type="date"></input>',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                    return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                });

                ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                    return new Date(viewValue);
                });
            },
        };
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/Vq65z/14/)</kbd>

That's a basic directive, there's still a lot of room for improvement, for example:

- allow the use of a custom format instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`,
- check that the date typed by the user is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginning to think myself that some intermediate string variable needs to replace the model bound to my date input. You say I should create directives for this to isolate the string variable -- do I understand it would be something along the lines of updating my actual `date` model when the input's value changes, and not binding the input to a model at all?

Comment: Cool, I was just about to start using __[this](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html)__ as a rough guide, looks like the technique is more or less the same!

Comment: You don't need `template` and `replace` if you already use a text input. For example I am using an angular-ui-datetimepicker which is a directive applied to a text input. I used the same code and it works.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks you very much for sharing with us. my vote +

Comment: isn't this `link the two variables` way to get `inf digest` exception?

Comment: @vp_arth No, because `dateFilter(new Date(dateString), 'yyyy-MM-dd') === dateString` and `new Date(dateFilter(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) === date` after a few iterations. There are never more than two digest cycles.

Comment: `new Date(...)` can't to be equal to date, because it's a new object. I check now: `new Date(2014, 11, 30) === new Date(2014, 11, 30)` is false. But yes, it's stopped, when strings equal...

Comment: anyway, I think something like `$scope.date.setTime((new Date(datestr)).getTime());` will be much better, because we don't replace `Date` object, just modify it.

Comment: @vp_arth This answer need to be rewritten anyway, in particular to make the edit less apparent. I'll take your comments into account for that, thank you very much.

Comment: Nice directive approach, but I think it would be better directive to be attribute type directive, not element type.

Answer (score 12):

***Why the value had to be given in yyyy-MM-dd?***

According to the [input type = date spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) of HTML 5, the value has to be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` since it takes the format of a valid `full-date` which is specified in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) as

```
full-date = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
```

There is nothing to do with Angularjs since the directive input doesn't support `date` type.

***How do I get Firefox to accept my formatted value in the date input?***

FF doesn't support `date` type of input for at least up to the version 24.0. You can get this info from [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). So for right now, if you use input with type being `date` in FF, the text box takes whatever value you pass in.

My suggestion is you can use [Angular-ui's Timepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and don't use the HTML5 support for the date input.

Comment: I'll definitely consider Angular's timepicker if I can't crack through it on my own, although I'm wondering about the support for custom styling...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this, it works fine:

```
<input type="date" class="form1"  
  value="{{date | date:MM/dd/yyyy}}"
  ng-model="date" 
  name="id" 
  validatedateformat 
  data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"
  maxlength="10" 
  id="id" 
  calendar 
  maxdate="todays"
  ng-click="openCalendar('id')">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" ng-click="openCalendar('id')"></span>
    </span>
</input>
```

Comment: what is openCalendar based upon?

Comment: Does having a closing tab for </input> violate w3c void element specification?  ...perhaps more importantly does this have any negative browser effects or parser issues.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have solved this way:

```
$scope.MyObject = // get from database or other sources;
$scope.MyObject.Date = new Date($scope.MyObject.Date);
```

and input type date is ok

Answer (score 0):

I've used ng-change:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('DateController', ['$rootScope', '$scope',
  function($rootScope, $scope) {
    function init() {
      $scope.startDate = new Date();
      $scope.endDate = $scope.startDate.addDays(14);
    }


    function load() {
      alert($scope.startDate);
      alert($scope.endDate);
    }

    init();
    // public methods
    $scope.load = load;
    $scope.setStart = function(date) {
      $scope.startDate = date;
    };
    $scope.setEnd = function(date) {
      $scope.endDate = date;
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-controller="DateController">
  <label class="item-input"> <span class="input-label">Start</span>
    <input type="date" data-ng-model="startDate" ng-change="setStart(startDate)" required validatedateformat calendar>
  </label>
  <label class="item-input"> <span class="input-label">End</span>
    <input type="date" data-ng-model="endDate" ng-change="setEnd(endDate)" required validatedateformat calendar>
  </label>
  <button button="button" ng-disabled="planningForm.$invalid" ng-click="load()" class="button button-positive">
    Run
  </button>
</div <label class="item-input"> <span class="input-label">Start</span>
<input type="date" data-ng-model="startDate" ng-change="setStart(startDate)" required validatedateformat calendar>
</label>
<label class="item-input"> <span class="input-label">End</span>
  <input type="date" data-ng-model="endDate" ng-change="setEnd(endDate)" required validatedateformat calendar>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fully functional directive for MEAN.JS (Angular.js, bootstrap, Express.js and MongoDb)

Based on @Blackhole ´s response, we just finished it to be used with mongodb and express.

It will allow you to save and load dates from a mongoose connector

Hope it Helps!!

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive(
  'dateInput',
  function(dateFilter) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: '<input type="date" class="form-control"></input>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
          return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        });

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(modelValue){
           return angular.toJson(modelValue,true)
          .substring(1,angular.toJson(modelValue).length-1);
        })

      }
    };
  });
```

The JADE/HTML:

```
div(date-input, ng-model="modelDate")
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Angular Material Design, you can use the datepicker component there and this will work in Firefox, IE etc.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Fair warning though - personal experience is that there are problems with this, and seemingly it is being re-worked at present. See here:

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4856