# Angular Bootstrap datepicker day issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap datepicker. Everythings works fine but when I select any date like `20-march-2015` it showing me `19-march-2015`(one day less from selected day).
Here is my code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpdDxL3GrQME1qBas1BZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This is a daylight saving issue.

Do you get the same issue with dates in February.

Looking at your example you can see the date is

`OutPut: "2015-04-26T23:00:00.000Z"`

For today :)

if I select 1st Jan, I get

`OutPut: "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`

Change your SPAN to

```
   <span>OutPut: {{formData.dueDate | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
```

And your good ( note the `| date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'` )

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need datepicker. Delete `datepicker` and use `type="date"`.

```
<input ng-model="formData.dueDate" type="date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate"
      class="form-control"  ng-click="data.isOpen = true">
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ciStIcjm2lkBZNOMXdwp?p=info)

Comment: Actually this is not all browser compatible. Not working on Mozilla and OS linux.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061757/angular-js-and-html5-date-input-value-how-to-get-firefox-to-show-a-readable-d

Comment: The example uses bootstrap, the down arrow that BOOT uses is not the same as the one that comes with your .. well my browser :)