# How to set default format as ('dd/mm/yyyy') in ng-bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

https://puu.sh/yThgV/bd55df9829.png

**html**

```
<label for="date">{{ "date" | translate }}</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control checking-field" id="date">
```

I want to get that format **('dd/mm/yyyy')**. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

extends my comment

In your app.module

```
import { NgbDatepickerConfig, NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbDateFRParserFormatter } from "./ngb-date-fr-parser-formatter"

@Component({
    providers: [{provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateFRParserFormatter}]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

In your NgbDateFRParserFormater

```
//your NgbDateFRParserFormater extends from NgbDateParserFormatter
//Is a Injectable that have two functions
@Injectable()
export class NgbDateFRParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct { //parse receive your string dd/mm/yyy
         //return a NgbDateStruct
         //calculate year,month and day from "value"
        return {year:year,month:month,day:day}
    }

    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string { //receive a NgbDateStruct
        //return a string
        return ''+date.day+'/'+date.month+'/'+date.year;
    }
}
```

Comment: I change your implementation for injectable to momentjs based on solution from here https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2072, I try your solution but has an error where NgbDateStruct value are numbers not string.

Answer (score 1):

My complete working solution:

Create a folder named "date-picker" and add the following files inside it.

date-picker > ngb-date-parser-formatter-ext.service.ts

date-picker > index.ts

The file

> date-picker > ngb-date-parser-formatter-ext.service.ts

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class NgbDateParserFormatterExtService extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
private dateSeparatorChar: string = "-";

// dateFormat should be "yyyy-MM-dd" or "dd-MM-yyyy" with the valid separator.
private dateFormat = `yyyy${this.dateSeparatorChar}MM${this.dateSeparatorChar}dd`;

parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
 if (value === "") {
   return null;
 }

 const dateString: string = value;
 const dateValues = dateString.split(this.dateSeparatorChar);

 if (dateValues.length !== 3) {
   return null;
 }

 let dayIndex: number;
 let yearIndex: number;

 if (this.dateFormat === "dd-MM-yyyy") {
   dayIndex = 0;
   yearIndex = 2;
 } else {
   dayIndex = 2;
   yearIndex = 0;
 }

 const year = Number(dateValues[yearIndex]);
 const month = Number(dateValues[1]);
 const day = Number(dateValues[dayIndex]);

 const date: NgbDateStruct = {
   year: year, month: month, day: day
 };

 return date;
}

format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
 if (date === null) {
   return "";
 }

 const dayString: string = date.day < 10 ? `0${date.day}` : `${date.day}`;
 const monthString: string = date.month < 10 ? `0${date.month}` : `${date.month}`;
 const separator = this.dateSeparatorChar;

 const dateString = this.dateFormat === "dd-MM-yyyy"
   ? `${dayString}${separator}${monthString}${separator}${date.year}`
   : `${date.year}${separator}${monthString}${separator}${dayString}`;

 return dateString;
 }
}
```

The file

> date-picker > index.ts

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { NgbDateParserFormatterExtService } from "./ngb-date-parser-formatter-ext.service";

export const NgbDateParserFormatterExtProvider =
  { provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateParserFormatterExtService };
```

In the file

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatterExtProvider } from "./common/services/date-picker";

@NgModule({

  providers: [...., NgbDateParserFormatterExtProvider],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your

> your-component1.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Publish Date</label><span> * </span>
    <input #datepicker="ngbDatepicker" class="form-control" name="datepicker" formControlName="publishDate"
      ngbDatepicker (click)="datepicker.toggle()" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  </div>
```

I'm using Reactive forms.

You can change the date format to "dd-MM-yyyy" or "dd/MM/yyyy" by setting the variable

```
private dateFormat = `yyyy${this.dateSeparatorChar}MM${this.dateSeparatorChar}dd`;
```

Regards..

Answer (score -3):

In general you need to use directive.

So, you can use one of ready-made date-time pickers for angular. Like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-date-time-input

Or create your own directive to make it work.

```
myModule.directive(
'dateInput',
function(dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input type="date"></input>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                return new Date(viewValue);
            });
        },
    };
});
```

I took this code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062552/3710672

Comment: NOT use a directive, you must use a 
NgbDateParserFormatter https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateParserFormatter, e.g. https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin/61ff1c3db355c74f4e56f485b566ab22

Comment: My bad that I didn't clarify or understand that it's Angular 2-5 and not the old one.

Comment: I need with angular 2 or 4.

Comment: Then Eliseo comment should help you.

Comment: sry, I wrong my bug report. I just use default html5 input.No use any plugin.

Comment: @user3675191 html5 input type date works fine in Chrome, but does not work in Internet Explorer 11 and some other browsers. Using polyfill also didn't work for me. To implement a cross browser datepicker, you will need to use ng-bootstrap datepicker or ngx-bootstrap datepicker or some other plugins.