# bind value in the view to the model before request is sent

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using anuglar with laravel.

laravel is returning a view which includes a users id as hidden input field.

After the view is loaded I want angular to bind the userid to variable and then use it to complete a http get request to the route someotherresource/userid.

When I hard code the route to angular controller it works fine but when I try to input the variable I get an undefined error which I think is because angular is trying to fire the request before the page is fully loaded and the value has been bound to the model

*app.js*

```
function resourceController($scope, $http) {
     /*$http.get('/resource' + $scope.userid).success(function(resource) {
        $scope.resource = resource;
     });*/
     console.log($scope.userid);
}
```

*html*

```
<div ng-controller="resourceController">
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="1" ng-model='userid'>
</form>
%% userid %%
</div>
```

edit: added console.log to the js and %% userid %% to the html.  this gives me undefined in the console and nothing displays for %% userid %%.

NB: I have changed the regular {{ }} syntax to %% %% to avoid conflicts the the back-end templating language.

Comment: A little more code needed, how are you using `$scope.resource` and what role does `ng-model=userid` play? Alternatively a jsFiddle example would be handy.

Comment: once the request is completed $scope.resource will be used to populate various fields that are sortable and searchable to the user.  I thought ng-model-'userid' would set the value of userid to the value of that hidden field? I am guessing that is incorrect as it isn't working.  I have updated the question with the exact code I am trying but it isn't much more than what was there this is as far as I have gotten with trying to do this unfortunately

Comment: I can't see any logic inside the Controller that looks like it would give you userid data? You'll need `$scope.userid`.

Comment: Thanks, even when changed to $scope.userid it is undefined though, that is my problem.  sorry actually that was a typo in my question http.get has been updated and its $scope.userid that is returning undefined.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to a jsFiddle and will take a look :)

Comment: Will do thanks. one sec

Comment: Hope a codepen is ok I havnt used jsfiddle http://codepen.io/Irish1/pen/AGhbe

Comment: You should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m

Comment: I would love to know what the downvote is for so I can refrain from making the same mistake again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the ng-model on hidden does not set the model value. It would not get set even in future. Better would be to use something like `ng-init` to set initial variable and do a watch on its change

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/WjJPT/

If you can define the ng-init on html about the the controller div, you don't even need to do a watch.

Comment: Thank you this is working and having this solved is going to help me big time

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `$scope.userid` variable. I'd also advise against using regular function declarations for your Controllers, Angular provides modules for you to do this so that the functions do not exist in the global scope:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('getRatingsController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.userid = 'Todd Motto';

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJfwd

Comment: Thank you for the controller info I was doing the same as a tutorial I followed I will change to this while my app is small, do you happen to have a link to an article or similar regarding why this is best practice? Just for my own further understanding.

Comment: Sure, I've written one: toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day