# Ng-Checked default value undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, default-value

I am wanting to know: how does one get a DEFAULT value for the ng-model inside a CHECKBOX to be true? The code i have will check the box but whenever i evaluate the model it keeps saying UNDEFINED...why is that?

```
           <input ng-change="docModel.check()"
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    ng-model="amountSelected" 
                                    ng-checked="true" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Value attribute on an input text box is ignored when there is a ng-model used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the default value when using AngularJS, simply give a value to the model variable in your controller:

```
$scope.amountSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

According the officiel AngularJS documentation ngChecked directive:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior

[link to the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)