# label hiding input text field value in md-input-container when retrieving with ng-value

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

When using angularjs to retrieve a value for a text input field with ng-value, the label the overlays the field doesn't transition above the field after the value is retrieved. I can only see the value in the input field after clicking on that field.

I'm using material's md-input-container:

```
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-value="profileInfo.name" ng-model="savedProfileInfo.name" class="provider-name" id="providerName" name="providerName" />
      </md-input-container>
```

Here's the Inspect Element code:

```
      <md-input-container class="">
        <label for="providerName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-value="profileInfo.name" ng-model="savedProfileInfo.name" class="provider-name ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid md-input" id="providerName" name="providerName" aria-invalid="false" value="a"><div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>
      </md-input-container>
```

You can clearly see that value="a" which was pulled after the page loaded using ng-value. But, the field still looks like this:

[image: input field with label overlay]

Only after I click on the field does it look how I would expect:

[image: input field after clicking on it]

Is this a bug? Am I missing something? I though AngularJS and Material were supposed to play nice.

> Available plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XNUv2IQZIxHkH2PM1asB?p=preview)

Comment: I think this is not an issue with angular-material...it's the desired behaviour of angular. You could have a look to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610282/angularjs-value-attribute-on-an-input-text-box-is-ignored-when-there-is-a-ng-m)

Comment: This would help if I were the one adding the value attribute but ng-value adds that dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a roundabout way troig's comment helped me figure this out.

This form is used to display and update a user's profile information. I was using *ng-model* to update the user's profile and ng-value to display any existing user profile info from the database.

*ng-value* spits back the *value=""* attribute which does not play nice with *md-input-container*. To get this to work properly, I removed *ng-value*, replaced *ng-model*'s value with *profileInfo.name*, and modified my controller to allow me to save *profileInfo.name* instead of *savedProfileInfo.name*.

Code translation:

```
    <form ng-submit="saveProfile(profileInfo)">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="profileInfo.name" class="provider-name" id="providerName" name="providerName" />
      </md-input-container>
```

Moral of the story, *ng-value* does not play nice with *md-input-container* and form labels.